# Does google API client Id and static map key both are same?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

Background:

We are using static map in our MVC Application.

Url : [http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={0}&zoom=13&markers=color:red%7Clabel:%7C{1}&size=500x350](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=%7B0%7D&zoom=13&markers=color:red%7Clabel:%7C%7B1%7D&size=500x350)

It was working fine but from last few days, I am receiving an exception saying "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden"

After reading few links, I got know that now google api needs api key for static map. But I am having some client Id, crypto key but not API key.

can we use static map without key?
Does client Id and api key are same?

Answer (score 0):

The client ID and cryptographic key is used with Premium plan license of Static Maps.

The API key is used with Standard plan version.

You can authenticate Static maps calls with client ID and digital signature as described in the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/get-api-key#client-id

I hope this helps!